# Merging files in Linux

Tags: uniq

I am using Cygwin to merge multiple files. However, I wanted to know if my approach is correct or not. This is both a question and a discussion :)

First, a little info about the files I have:

1. Both the files have ASCII as well as NON ASCII Characters.
2. File1 has **7899097** lines in it and a size of ~ **70.9 Mb**
3. File2 has **14344391** lines in it and a size of ~ **136.6 Mb**

**File Encoding Information:**

```
$ file -bi file1.txt
text/x-c++; charset=unknown-8bit

$ file -bi file2.txt
text/x-c++; charset=utf-8

$ file -bi output.txt
text/x-c++; charset=unknown-8bit
```

This is the method I am following to merge the two files, sort them and then remove all the duplicate entries:

1. I create a temp folder and place both the text files inside it.
2. I run the following commands to merge both the files but keep a line break between the two

   ```
   for file in *.txt; do
       cat $file >> output.txt
       echo >> output.txt
   done
   ```

The resulting output.txt file has **22243490** lines in it and a size of 207.5 Mb

Now, if I run the sort command on it as shown below, I get an error since there are Non ASCII characters (maybe unicode, wide characters) present inside it:

```
sort -u output.txt
string comparison failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

So, I set the environment variable **LC_ALL** to C and then run the command as follows:

```
cat output.txt | sort -u | uniq >> result.txt
```

And, the result.txt has **22243488** lines in it and a size of 207.5 Mb.

So, result.txt is the same as output.txt

Now, I already know that there are many duplicate entries in output.txt, then why the above commands are not able to remove the duplicate entries?

Also, considering the large size of the files, I wanted to know if this is an efficient method to merge multiple files, sort them and then unique them?

Comment: Is it fair to summarize your question as - be able to sort and merge multi-byte character data files? Are the files set to UTF-8 encoding (is the BOM set properly?)

Comment: I have edited the post and specified the file encoding format as well. No, the question is not just about sorting and merging, I have given some more details specific to what I want to know. Yes, sorting, merging and removing duplicates is also what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'd use

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt other-files.* | recode enc1..enc2 | sort | uniq > file3.txt
```

but watch out - this could cause problem with some big file sizes, counted in gigabytes ( or bigger), anyway with hundreds of megabytes should probably go fine. If I'd want real efficiency, e.g. having really huge files, I'd first remove single-file duplicates, then sort it, merge one after one, and then sort again and remove duplicate lines again. Theoretically uniq -c  and grep filter could remove duplicates. Try to avoid falling into some unneeded sophistication of the solution :)

http://catb.org/~esr/writings/unix-koans/two_paths.html

edited:

```
mv file1.txt file1_iso1234.txt 
mv file2.txt file2_latin7.txt
ls file*.txt |while read line; do cat $line |recode $(echo $line|cut -d'_' -f2 |cut -d'.' -f1)..utf8 ; done | sort | uniq > finalfile.txt
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. In my case, there is an issue with the encoding of both the files. So, how would I use the recode option? Could you elaborate over that? Moreover, my command looks exactly like yours but still does not remove the duplicates, what could be the reason?

Comment: Certainly you need to sort before uniq, and you need to have all input with the same encoding before you sort. So, if files have different encodings, you need to recode it from appropriate, to some common encoding you decide to use, probably utf8. To solve it quickly, you could rename files to contain encoding in file name

    mv file1.txt file1_iso1234.txt
    mv file2.txt file2_latin7.txt

and then e.g.


    ls file*.txt |while read line; do cat $line |recode $(echo $line|cut -d'_' -f2 |cut -d'.' -f1)..utf8 | .. [ end so on  after pipe with sort, uniq, etc.]

something like that..

Comment: Thanks. However, recode is not available in Cygwin. I have understood your solution though. I tried iconv to convert from us_ascii encoding to utf-8 and it gave an error while parsing the original file. I will try your solution too.